# I could not see any output of this react code

Tags: reactjs

1.I am new to react, I could not understand what's wrong with this code.

2.I have HTML file where I have added a div with id "container" to it.

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
      return (
         <div>
            {this.props.children}
         </div>
      );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
      <HelloWorld>A</HelloWorld>
      <HelloWorld>B</HelloWorld>
   </div>,
   document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: check console, are you getting any error message? can you show the full html file in which you are using this code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: currently i am using codepen.io online editor.

Comment: currently i am using codepen.io online editor.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top for JSX and react element,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: I am using codepen. so i have already added these libraries there

Comment: I am using codepen. so i have already added these libraries there